# Is there a tutorial or a book doing MVVM + DI and using Data from DataBase all in one?

Tags: database, mvvm, dependency-injection

It's possible to find tutorials on MVVM and DI, somewhat harder about getting Data from database properly into GUI.

Finding something that talks about all these things and how they integrate is near impossible.

I guess some people will say that it doesn't matter and all stands independently but I don't believe it. Especially considering MVVM and Data as I find keeping a tight grip on data managing while doing MVVM to be the hardest part.

So is there anything I could use, and I don't wan't some small simple problem solved but something near complete, at least steps from DB to GUI dynamically done. I'm willing to pay for such a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among many other things my book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236) discusses all of those things. However, the subjects is DI first and foremost, with MVVM and data access only incidentals. However, you may find some of the code examples accompanying the book helpful.

Comment: Yeah I've heard about your book. Is it available online somewhere as PDF or hardcopy only. There are few foreign language books available in my country.

Comment: Ok stupid question since I now notice your hyperlink, sorry about that.

Comment: Ingó, the link Mark gave you points to both hardcopy and eBook offerings. I think it's a great resource!

Comment: @Mark Seeman. Is this *still* not available in hard copy?? I have been waiting for ages to buy it as such. Not until August?? What's up with that...

Comment: Writing a book takes time... You should try it one day ;)

Comment: @Berryl: And remember, this also available electronically in the MEAP (I have the book on preorder myself but if I needed it, that's where I'd go)

Comment: @Mark Seeman. Lol, didn't mean to make it sound trivial. And I wouldn't want to read it if I hadn't read and respected other things you have done. I really meant what's up with finishing it, and what is missing, so I can decide if I want to suck it up and download the pdf (yuk!)? It seems like all of the chapters are written and available...

Comment: The book is currently in its third and final peer review. After that I'll need to address the comments received from the reviewers. This whole process takes at least a month since reviewers need time to read the book, and I need to time to address their issues. After that, the book needs to go through proof reading, typesetting and other 'publishing' steps not too familiar to me, and finally it can be printed (which also takes time). So even thought it's close to being finished, it still takes some time to get it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [Prism guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) provided by Microsoft [Patterns & Practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default) group. Prism is actually complete architectural approach to build enterprise level solutions. But it contains StockTrader Reference Implementation application that is built using DI, MVVM and includes interaction with data storage (they use XML files as data storage to provide easy distribution, but it really doesn't matter what data storage is used). Also, the guidance contains several small quickstart projects which emphasize particular part of the architecture. There is comprehensive documentation and [active community](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) around Prism, so you can find answers to any question. And it is completely free.

Comment: I've actually considered using PRISM and I wan't to learn it sometime, but I fear it might be to big for my current project. I wouldn't use it's modularity for example.

Comment: I agree that it is too powerful for most projects, but one of the best advantages of Prism is that you can use all its features independently.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Prism guidance already mentioned, I highly recommend Karl Shifflett's [MVVM In-the-Box](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab5f02f-0c54-453c-b437-8e8d57eb9942/) tutorial. It has great content and also encourages you to experiment with code as you progress through the topics (it is integrated with Visual Studio).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. The BookLibrary shows how to use MVVM, DI with MEF and data management with Entity Framework and SQL Compact Edition.